# Finding an exact pattern multiple times using grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

The lines of the input files look like this:

```
d-- s--:--- a++ C- UH++++ P++++ L--- E-- W- N++++ O-- M(+) !V PS- PE+++ Y++ PGP t+ 5++ X++ R+++ tv b+++ DI+++
```

I want to find the lines that have the pattern `X+++` at least 6 times, with X being any letter. I've tried the following command: grep `\(.*\+\+\+[[:space:]]\)\{6\}` but this seems to also match the pattern `X++++`.

Example inputs:

```
d-- s--:--- a++ C- UH++++ P++++ L--- E-- W- N++++ o+++++ K+++ w+++ O-- M(+) !V PS- PE+++ Y++ PGP t+

C+++ U- P++++ L+++ E W- N+ o++($) K-- w+ O-- M-- V-$ PS PE++ Y-- PGP++++ t+++ 5+++ X+++ R* tv b++ DI+ D+++ !G
```

Desired output:

```
C+++ U- P++++ L+++ E W- N+ o++($) K-- w+ O-- M-- V-$ PS PE++ Y-- PGP++++ t+++ 5+++ X+++ R* tv b++ DI+ D+++ !G
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? We need to know which `grep` implementation you have to know what features are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want `{6,}` for "6 or more", because `{6}` means "exactly 6". Next, if you just add the `{6,}` to the end of the pattern, that would only match on consecutive patterns. So this would match:

```
aa X+++ X+++ X+++ X+++ X+++ X+++
```

But this would not

```
X+++  a X+++  a X+++ X+++ X+++ X+++
```

So you need to use `(${pattern}.*){6,}`, meaning "find '`$pattern` and then 0 or more characters' 6 or more times". Also, you want to match not only `[[:space:]]` but also the end of the line in case the final `X+++` is the last thing on the line. Something like this:

```
grep -E '([^+]\+\+\+([[:space:]]|$).*){6,}' file
```

Note that if you use `-E` (or `-P`), you need to escape the `+` but you don't need to escape the `(`, `)`, `|`, `{` or `}` and if you don't use `-E`, you don't need to escape the `+`, but you do need to escape the others if you want them to not be taken literally. So, without `-E`, that would be:

```
grep '\([^+]+++\([[:space:]]\|$\).*\)\{6,\}' file
```